# Mailchimp API returning strange response

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, character-encoding, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm getting a strange issue using the Mailchimp API, I'm just trying to exchange my short lived code which I've got from them for an access token as per their OAuth documentation [here](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/how-to-use-oauth2/#flow).

However, I'm getting what appears to be some encoding issue with the response I'm getting back. This is what I have in PHP: (it can be reproduced even without substituting the correct client_id, client_secret etc.)

```
<?php

  //### INITIALISE CURL #############################
  $curl = curl_init();

  //### SET CURL OPTIONS ############################
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,"https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/token" );

  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXX&client_secret=XXXXXXXXXXX&code=XXXXXXX&redirect_uri=https://mailchimp.test.com" );
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  "Content-Type: multipart/form-data")); 

  //### EXECUTE CURL ###############################
  $result = curl_exec($curl);
  if(curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) =='0') {
    echo curl_error($curl);
  }
  curl_close($curl);

  echo $result;

?>
```

I get this response ($result):

```
�M��    �0F�UJ�N�NQ� %`��' "�Ћ���nb��f=�&9����i'f��]�~j*$��W��Reg��_T1-���;�oc
```

How can I fix this so that the response I get is correct as per the example response on Mailchimp's docs? (below)

**Example Response:**

```
{"access_token":"5c6ccc561059aa386da9d112215bae55","expires_in":0,"scope":null}
```

Comment: Where is your authorize call?
https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=635959587059&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.8%2Foauth%2Fcomplete.php

Comment: @Sarang Damkondwar That happens in a separate PHP script (before this process of exchanging a code for an access token), and then the user is then returned from mailchimp (as per redirect_uri).

Comment: ohk, Can you please console the result with some other function instead of echo, may be object one? Also please check if you set encoding anywhere!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the following to your code you will get the correct response:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
```

For example

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
```

Found this here:

https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api/pull/69/files

See this article also which may clear up the matter

https://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/design/i-have-strange-characters-in-my-content